# Cannot create *.appxupload" package for Windows 10 Store Apache Cordova project:

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I cannot create *.appxupload" package for
Windows 10 Store Apache Cordova  project:
(Visual Studio 2015 release 4.6.00079)

Experimenting with a new (template only)   project, 
I found that  "...appxpackage"  file is created when target platform 
is Windows 8.1 and is not created (created only "...appx") when target platform is Windows 10.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and have already been resolved in recent Tools for Cordova Update 10.

We can get the update and additional info from:
http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/2016/06/01/announcing-update-10.html

And we've also published a workaround before shipping this update.
http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/2016/05/06/windows-store-packaging.html